# How to change Notification Image or Icon in React Native with OneSignal Dashboard?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-onesignal

For doing this first you need to go to this url and create icon by following the creating steps
-After creating icon then click on download button.
-you will see zip file then extract that file then you will see something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJZgj.png)
-then copy / move this file to [Your Project > Android > app > src > main > res > {Paste here}

for adding accent color / background color to notification there is an option in onesignal > push notification message section [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNjKC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6J4A.png) add in accent what you want on background.

-Add that image name which you have pasted to android folder (eg-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNGi6.png))

URL -  http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit

If you find any difficulties then please message me.